# Salesforce compatible Regex for E. 164 phone number format

Tags: validation

Can someone help me find a Salesforce compatible Regex for E. 164 phone number format. I found the below regex on a Twilio site.

```
^\+?[1-9]\d{1,14}$
```

But when I try use it in a Salesforce validation rule (see Salesforce syntax below) it throws a syntax error.

```
!REGEX(Phone,"^\+?[1-9]\d{1,14}$")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the backslashes in your regex because backslashes are escape characters in Salesforce. From the [Formula Operators and Functions doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5):

> Regular expression syntax is based on Java Platform SE 6 syntax. However, backslash characters (\) must be changed to double backslashes (\\) because the backslash is an escape character in Salesforce.

Your final formula will look like:

```
!REGEX(Phone,"^\\+?[1-9]\\d{1,14}$")
```